# Apache2 - Changing the php memory limit for specific urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, memory, httpd.conf

I was wondering if it's possible to change the php_value memory_limit for a specific url.

I've tried using `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')`, as well as setting the `suhosin memory.limit` to 256M, but it just doesn't work, whenever I do `var_dump(ini_set('memory_limit', 256M))`i just get `bool(false)`.

I was wondering if there is a way of changing httpd.include to change the php memory limit for a specific url. At the moment i have this:

```
<LocationMatch "docs/download/">
        php_value memory_limit "256M"
</LocationMatch>
```

so if I navigate to docs/download/ in the url I want it to up the memory limit, but doing `ini_get('memory_limit')` still only returns the memory_limit that's set in .htaccess which is 128M.

Okay, so I've actually solved this. It was an issue with Suhosin. I had changed the file in `/etc/php5/conf.d` but there was another Suhosin file in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` that I failed to change. Doing this fixed the issue.

Comment: `"256M"` should be a string in the Àpache config

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've actually solved this. It was an issue with Suhosin. I had changed the file in /etc/php5/conf.d but there was another Suhosin file in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d that I failed to change. Doing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a string for **both** parameters.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

furthermore, the result of ini_set is false because of the syntax error, calling `var_dump` on it will only show you the result of the set, not the value that its reporting.  You need [ini_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) for that.

```
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a typo on my end when writing this, I have been using strings for both parameters in my actual application. And I know that, but using 'ini_set' will allow me to check if the set has failed or not, I could use 'ini_get' too I guess